# Do I need to reinit datagram socket on network change?

Tags: java, android, sockets, udp, package

I'm working on an Android app that uses datagram socket and packet for receiving and sending UDP packeges.

Receiving is done in a thread:

```
public UnitedReceiver(int port) {
        try {
            message = new UnitedMessage();
            packet = new DatagramPacket(message.data, message.data.length);
            socket = new DatagramSocket(port);
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run(){
        isRunning = true;

        while(isRunning){
            try {
                socket.receive(packet);

                if(!Network.compare(packet.getAddress(), Params.local_ip)){

                    //namesti kodove i length
                    message.data_length = packet.getLength();
                    new UnitedParser(message, packet.getAddress());
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        socket.close();
    }
```

Sending is done using static function:

```
public static void send(InetAddress adr, int port, byte[] data, int length) throws Exception{
        DatagramPacket packet;
        DatagramSocket socket = null;

        try{
            packet = new DatagramPacket(data, length, adr, port);
            socket = new DatagramSocket();
            socket.setSoTimeout(timeout);

            socket.send(packet);

            socket.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            socket.close();
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

I'm interested what happens when the network is changed, and by extension ip address of the device.
Sending shouldn't be problem, it always creates new socket and packet.

But UnitedReceiver is in a infinite loop so there could be?
Do I have to reinit socket and packet in UnitedReceiver on network change?

Comment: You don't need the compare step. Just connect the socket to the desired source address.

Comment: I need it because I receive packages from various sources on the same port.

Comment: So why are you only doing one source-address comparison?

Comment: I can receive my own broadcasts [: So I need them to weed them out.